# Processing Phase Cancellation on WAV file generates WAV file with no sound

Tags: java, android, audio, wav

So I am generating WAV file with Phase Cancellation. But generated WAV file plays but with no sound. Have used multiple players and devices but no sound. At first I copied the Header to the target file. Then,

Reading Data part of the WAV file and getting Audio Data Array

```
 long arrLength = source.length() - Wav_header_size;

    byte[] arr = new byte[(int) arrLength];

    RandomAccessFile filein;
    filein = new RandomAccessFile(source, "rw");
    filein.seek(Wav_header_size);
    filein.read();
    filein.write(arr,0, arr.length);
    filein.close();
```

Getting Channel arrays from the Audio Data

```
short[] shortAudioArray = new short[arr.length/2];
    short[] channelLeft = new short[arr.length/4];
    short[] channelRight = new short[arr.length/4];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(arr).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shortAudioArray);

for(int i=0, j=0; i< shortAudioArray.length;i+=2, ++j){
        if(channelLeft.length>j && channelLeft[j]!=0)
            channelLeft[j] = shortAudioArray[i];
        else
            break;
        if(channelRight.length>j && channelRight[j]!=0)
            channelRight[j] = shortAudioArray[i+1];
        else
            break;
    }
```

Processing Phase cancellation by negating one phase and then merging

```
 for(int i =0;i< data2.length;i++) {
        data2[i] = (short) -data2[i];
    }

    for(int i=0,j=0; j< dstAudio.length;i++,j=j+2) {
        if(data1.length>i && data1[i]!=0)
            dstAudio[j] = data1[i];
        else
            break;
        if(data2.length>i && data2[i]!=0)
            dstAudio[j+1] = data2[i];
        else
            break;
    }

   byte[] bytesLast = new byte[dstAudio.length * 2];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytesLast).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().put(dstAudio);
```

This way same size Audio WAV file is getting generated but with no sound.
Can anyone please correct me if I am wrong in anyway in the whole process?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you attempting to generate a new stereo file which is a phase inverted version of an original file or something else entirely?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Is the process I am using alright or I need to follow something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have solved the issue by manipulating the byte array through inverting the bits one by one not producing or converting to anymore short arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Java provides classes that handle the formatting and other structural aspects of the .wav file. I strongly suggest making use of those tools rather than attempting to write your own .wav headers and such.

You can read more about these tools at [the Oracle tutorial on sound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/). The sixth in the series (Using Files and Format Converters) has a subsection on writing audio files.

Comment: Thanks. Okay I will look into that.

Comment: But  I really need to make this code work. So it would be great if anyone points out the way through it.

Comment: Step 1, play a wav file with a SourceDataLine (there are multiple tutorials). Step 2, substitute your code (the part that creates PCM in byte form) for the role usually played by AudioInputStream.